# correct way to write to pipe line by line in Python

Tags: python, shell, unix, subprocess, pipe

How can I write to stdout from Python and feed it simultaneously (via a Unix pipe) to another program? For example if you have

```
# write file line by line
with open("myfile") as f:
  for line in f:
    print line.strip()
```

But you'd like that to go line by line to another program, e.g. `| wc -l` so that it outputs the lines in `myfile`. How can that be done? thanks.

Comment: Did you try it? You might find that this already works :) You just need to write to standard output (represented as the file-like object `sys.stdout` in Python), which `print` also does.

Comment: Do you actually want to do both simultaneously? If so, both you and `wc` will be writing to the same standard output. Is that what you want?

Comment: @abarnert: I want the program to basically write the stdin which ``wc -l`` is getting, so yes, I want to do both simultaneously if I understand your question... meaning I want to write to ``wc -l`` and actually call ``wc -l``, so not just write to stdin unlike what @Thomas suggested.

Comment: @user248237 Look at [the `subprocess` module](http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/subprocess.html).

Comment: It wouldn't be hard to duplicate the functionality of `wc -l` in python. Then you can eliminate this subprocess stuff.

Comment: @Keith: ``wc -l`` is just an example... I would like to call arbitrary programs that read from stdin and write back to stdout

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you want to pipe `python` to `wc` externally, that's easy, and will just work:

```
python myscript.py | wc -l
```

If you want to tee it so its output both gets printed and gets piped to `wc`, try `man tee` or, better, your shell's built-in fancy redirection features.

If you're looking to run `wc -l` from within the script, and send your output to both stdout and it, you can do that too.

First, use [`subprocess.Popen`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#popen-constructor) to start `wc -l`:

```
wc = subprocess.Popen(['wc', '-l'], stdin=subprocess.PIPE)
```

Now, you can just do this:

```
# write file line by line
with open("myfile") as f:
  for line in f:
    stripped = line.strip()
    wc.stdin.write(stripped + '\n')
```

That will have `wc`'s output go to the same place as your script's. If that's not what you want, you can also make its `stdout` a PIPE. In that case, you want to use [`communicate`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen.communicate) instead of trying to get all the fiddly details right manually.

Comment: I would like to redirect ``wc``'s output to a file. In that case I can just pass ``stdout=filehandle`` in ``Popen`` right?

Comment: @user248237: Exactly. And if you want to call `sort`, pipe that to `grep`, and pipe that to `wc`, and direct that to a file… see http://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#replacing-shell-pipeline. But if you're doing a lot of this, you may want to consider one of the many higher-level shell-like libraries at PyPI, or just using bash instead of Python.

Comment: Yes, you should `wc.wait()` when you're done. For a quick&dirty script, you can just exit, but in a real program, you'll always want to `wait` (or `communicate` or something else equivalent).

Comment: true but the manual says that if you set stdout/stderr to ``PIPE`` then wait will hang so I guess in that case you don't call it? call communicate instead?

Comment: @user248237: But you didn't set `stdout` to `PIPE`, you set it to a file descriptor, right? You set `stdin` to `PIPE`, but that doesn't matter. (Of course there are ways to get deadlocks with `stdin=PIPE`—or even without it, you can write code in the child that's waiting for you to do something, not do that, and then block on `wait`… but that's not what that warning is about.)